# What is difference between .NET Features and C# features? (with examples please)

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I feel this is very commonly misunderstood and I always end up getting confused between the two.
When we say CLR feature (.NET feature) or C# feature, are they same or they vary

Edit:
I feel most of the folks have misunderstood my question. I am not asking the core difference between C# and .NET, rather was little curious about the feature wise classification. Like garbage collection is a CLR feature or anonymous types are language feature, so on and so forth

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the different between C# and .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724864/what-is-the-different-between-c-sharp-and-net)

Comment: I feel most of the folks have misunderstood my question. I am not asking the core difference between C# and .NET, rather was little curious about the feature wise classification. Like garbage collection is a CLR feature or anonymous types are language feature, so on and so forth

Comment: I see, your edit helped to clarify that. I cannot undo my duplicate vote, but it wouldn't help much, since most of the close votes are for being "not constructive", probably because of the danger of "extended discussion".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's worth being very clear between language features, library features and runtime features.

Some examples:

- The null-coalescing `??` operator, partial classes and lambda expressions are entirely language features
- Garbage collection is pretty much a pure runtime feature; the language interacts with it somewhat via finalizers, but that's all
- Generics are a mixture of a language and runtime feature - although notably the CLR had support for generic variance significantly before F# exposed it. Libraries use generics, of course.
- Nullable types are a mixture of all three: the CLR needs to know about them for boxing purposes (and struct constraints on generics), the `Nullable<T>` type itself is defined in the libraries, and the C# language has support for them in various ways (for example using the `?` type suffix)

Comment: @Misam: Does your unacceptance of this answer indicate that you're still looking for more detail?

Comment: Yes some more feature classification would be great and that would add to my knowledge.

Comment: @Misam: Well I don't really want to go through every feature in the language, runtime and frameworks. I'd be here forever. Do you have anything specific in mind?

Comment: Oh yes ! I understand that, I am pretty clear now after going through your 'C# In Depth' site and other resources. Thank you very much Jon for the response and patience :)