# Using string interpolation and nameof in .VS 2015 NET 4.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.5, .net-4.6

I'm using things like `$"hello {person}"` and `nameof(arg1)` in my code, but on checking the project properties I'm targeting .NET 4.5.

Is this okay?  I thought these things were introduced in 4.6.

The project builds and runs okay on my machine - but I'm worried something will go wrong when I deploy it.

Comment: See [Untangling the Versions](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx) by Jon Skeet. Although it doesn't cover C# 6.0 but the concept is same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a compiler feature, not a framework feature. We successfully use both features with our .NET 3.5 projects in Visual Studio 2015.

In a nutshell, the compiler translates `$"hello {person}"` to `String.Format("hello {0}", person)` and `nameof(arg1)` to `"arg1"`. It's just syntactic sugar.

The runtime sees a `String.Format` call (or a string literal "arg1", respectively) and does not know (nor care) what the original source code looked like. `String.Format` is supported since the early days of the .NET Framework, so there's nothing preventing you from targeting an earlier version of the framework.

Comment: See my answer for a slight wrinkle on this around `FormattableString`.

Answer (score 11):

The existing answers talk about this being a C# 6 feature without a .NET framework component.

This is entirely true of `nameof` - but only *somewhat* true of string interpolation.

String interpolation will use `string.Format` in most cases, but if you're using .NET 4.6, it can *also* convert an interpolated string into a `FormattableString`, which is useful if you want invariant formatting:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using static System.FormattableString;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
        double d = 0.5;
        string local = $"{d}";
        string invariant = Invariant($"{d}");
        Console.WriteLine(local);     // 0,5
        Console.WriteLine(invariant); // 0.5
    }    
}
```

Obviously this wouldn't work if `$"{d}"` simply invoked a call to `string.Format`... instead, in this case it calls `string.Format` in the statement assigning to `local`, and calls [`FormattableStringFactory.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.formattablestringfactory.create) in the statement assigning to `invariant`, and calls [`FormattableString.Invariant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formattablestring.invariant(v=vs.110).aspx) on the result. If you try to compile this against an earlier version of the framework, `FormattableString` won't exist so it won't compile. You can provide your own implementation of `FormattableString` and `FormattableStringFactory` if you really want to, though, and the compiler will use them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

These things were introduced in `C#6`. `.Net` has nothing to do with it. So as long as you are using a **C#6 compiler**, you can use these features.

[What is the difference between C# and .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2724864/3107430)

So yes, **it is okay** to use them in a project targeting .Net 4.5.